# Nginx 404 not found in subdir

Tags: php, nginx

Okay, i setup a debian install with **ispconfig3** ,**php5-fpm** and **nginx**, the main site, drupal is working fine, even perfect. But i also have a **modded** phpbb3 board, in a **subdir**, named '**forum**'.

Now for some reason i get the following error from nginx when accesing the dir:

**'ERROR 500 - Internal Server Error!'**

This is the content of the nginx directiv field(for vhost):

```
# search for already compressed files
  gzip_static on;
  gzip on;

  # some images have no mime type
  default_type image/jpeg;

  # 404 generated from php can be rather slow. Uncomment with care
  error_page 404 /index.php;

  # disallow access to version control directory, but return 404, not to disclose information
  location /.git {
    return 404;
  }

  # robots.txt is important for search engines
  location /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
  }

  # This is mostly based on Drupal's stock .htaccess
  location ~* ^.+(\.(txt|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
    return 404;
  }

  # serve imagecache files directly or redirect to drupal if they do not exist
  location ~* imagecache {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    try_files $uri @drupal;
  }

  # Drupal 7 image stylef
  location ~* image/generate {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    try_files $uri @drupal;
  }

  # serve static files directly
  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|swf|flv)$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    expires 30d;
  }

location @rewrite {
      # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
      # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
break;
    }

  # This rewrites pages to be sent to PHP processing
  location @drupal {
rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /index.php?q=$1  last;

}

location / {
    try_files $uri @cache;
  }

  # This will try to see if we have a boost file in place. no harm done if this is not used
  location @cache {
    # queries, drupal cookies, or not GET methods, all require PHP processing.
    if ($query_string ~ ".+") {
      return 405;
    }
    if ($http_cookie ~ "DRUPAL_UID" ) {
      return 405;
    }
    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
      return 405;
    }
    error_page 405 = @drupal;

    # Drupal uses 1978 - I am 4 years older than Dries :)
    add_header Expires "Tue, 22 Sep 1974 08:00:00 GMT";
    add_header Cache-Control "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    try_files /cache/normal/$host/${uri}_.html /cache/mobile/$host/${uri}_.html /cache/perm/$host/${uri}_.css /cache/perm/$host/${uri}_.js /cache/$host/0$uri.html /cache/$host/0${uri}/index.html @drupal;
  }


location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                       fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                       fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
                       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                       fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }

location /forum {
               root /var/www/ashladan.net/web;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/forum/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /var/www/ashladan.net/web;
                       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                       fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                       fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                       fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
                       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                       fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                       fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
               }
               location ~* ^/forum/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /var/www/ashladan.net/web;
               }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be standard PHP response for uncaught exception / fatal / syntax error with no output.

You can either turn on error logging in php.ini and check your log file, or just at the beginning of your index.php file in this directory add two lines:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
```

So if it is PHP's fault you will get more details on this error.

Comment: Hello, dev-null-dweller. this is the first thing i did, but it hase no use, since it aint parsing the php script, the logs don't mention any error about that dir....